# Search for line in string Python

Tags: python, string, file, search, line

I try to check for every line in a file if it's in another string (output of a command that I executed).
It prints me "not good" every time...
Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
connections = subprocess.Popen(["vol connscan"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = connections.communicate()  
file = open('/opt/hila','r')
    for line in file:
        if line in out:
            print "good"
        else:
            print "not good"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to strip the newline if you are looking for a substring:

```
 if line.rstrip() in out
```

You can also use `check_output` to get the output and pass a list of args:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["vol", "connscan"])
```

You should also use `with` to open your files:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["vol","connscan"])
with  open('/opt/hila') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() in out:
            print("good")
        else:
            print("bad")
```

You may be getting output from stderr so you should also verify in your own code that `out` actually contains anything and it is not just an empty string.

If you are looking for an exact line match make `out` a set of lines and you have verified or corrected to get output:

```
st = set(out.splitlines())
```

If you are looking for a substring a newline will mean the check can fail:

```
In [2]: line = "foo\n"

In [3]: out = "foo bar"

In [4]: line in out
Out[4]: False

In [5]: line.rstrip() in out
Out[5]: True
```